# inheriting attr_accessor inside a constant

Tags: ruby

I have a class with attr_accessor set like this:

```
class Human
    ATTRIBUTES = [:name]
    attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
end
```

it works like a charm, allows me to keep attributes inside ATTRIBUTES constant. Problem is I would like to have a class Student inheriting from a Human class, without the need to put attr_accessor every time.
Basically what i would like to have is this:

```
class Student < Human
    ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :school]
end
```

unfortunately when i do

```
Student.new.school
```

i get no method error, because attr_accessor is loaded from Human and not a Student. What construction should i use to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Student class as such doesnt have attr_accessor so it doesn't know that there is an attribute with school. if you want to have school recognized, you should either have attr_accessor in the Student class or have the school attib declared in Human class.

Comment: Do you even know what `attr_accessor` does? From what I can understand of your question, you don't. That seems to be the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

I personally agree with @lcguida's answer, but I came up with a little experiment if you insist on following the pattern you proposed. The other answers already covered why your solution didn't work, so I'm not getting into that here.

The first thing that came to mind was to call `attr_accessor` on the `self.inherited` callback on the parent class, but unfortunately the child's body is not loaded until later. Even so, where there's a will, there's a way. If you're using Ruby 2.0 or later, the following implementation will work.

```
module LazyAttrAccessorizer
  def self.extended(obj)
    TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
      if obj == t.self
        obj.send :attr_accessor, *obj::ATTRIBUTES
        t.disable
      end
    end
  end
end

class Human
  extend LazyAttrAccessorizer
  ATTRIBUTES = [:name]
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.extend LazyAttrAccessorizer
  end
end

class Student < Human
  ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :school]
  # ATTRIBUTES = [:school] would also work as expected, but I think you'd like to be literal there.
end

> Student.new.respond_to?(:name)
=> true
> Student.new.respond_to?(:school)
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, while I don't get the need to keep the attributes in a array, `Student` class will already inherit the `attr_accessor`'s defined in it's parent class.

For example:

```
class Human
  attr_accessor :name, :gender
end

class Student < Human
  attr_accessor :school
end
```

Student class now has :name, :gender and :school `attr_accessor`'s:

```
 > Student.new.respond_to?(:name)
 => true
 > Student.new.respond_to?(:name=)
 => true
 > Student.new.respond_to?(:school)
 => true
 > Student.new.respond_to?(:school=)
 => true
```

Human also responds to `:name` and `:gender`

```
> Human.new.respond_to?(:name)
=> true
> Human.new.respond_to?(:gender)
=> true
```

But not to school

```
> Human.new.respond_to?(:school)
=> false
```

It's cleaner, it's the ruby way, easier to understand.